# вывод рекомендуемых товаров в каждой карточке на странице категории

Tags: opencart

Мне нужно в каждой карточке товара на странице категории вывести рекомендованные товары.

У меня обычный опенкарт с нестандартным шаблоном. Начал писать вручную. Я сейчас пытаюсь по аналогии с файлом product.tpl сделать так же с category.tpl.
В product.tpl нашел строчку `include(......../related.php)`. Она тянет необходимые мне рекомендуемые товары.
Когда я использую то же в файле category.tpl, мне тянет все товары, которые есть в категории.
И я не могу понять как это исправить.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ответ подразумевает, что т.н. **рекомендованные товары** - это модуль, который включается и инстанциируется как и любой другой стандартный модуль.

В **opencart** для вывода дополнительных блоков, таких как кастомные html-структуры, сайдбары, слайдеры и прочиемодули на различных страницах сайта, существует отдельный пункт меню - **Схемы(Layouts)**. Там вы найдёте список всех основных шаблонов сайта. В Вашем случае это пункты **Категория(Category)** и **Продукт(Product)**.
Зайдя в них вы найдёте название схемы, магазин которому данная схема назачена(для мультимагазина), роут схемы, и набор модулей, дополнительно подключаемых в схеме
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Здесь в списке `Mодуль` выбирается необходимый из набора `дополнения > модули`, `Расположение` указывает относительное положение модуля. По умолчанию OC имеет 4е модульные позиции - верх/низ/лево/право. В .tpl шаблонах за их вывод отвечают переменные `$column_right; $column_left; $content_top; $content_bottom;` Модули в них выводятся списком в соответствии с сортировкой, указанной в `Порядок сортировки` (по-умолчанию в порядке добавления)

### **UPD:**

**Добавление "рекомендуемых" из карты товара в каталог**

Раздел карты товара "**Рекомендуемые**" формируется следующим образом:

```
#catalog/controller/product/product.php:
$data['products'] = array();//->$products
$results = $this->model_catalog_product->getProductRelated($this->request->get['product_id']);
foreach ($results as $result) {
    #... code ...
    #... code ...
    $data['products'][] = array(
        'product_id'  => $result['product_id'],
        #... code ...
        #... code ...
        );
}    

#catalog/view/theme/default(your_theme)/product/product.tpl:
<?php if ($products) { ?>
```

Собственно, часть из контроллера товара необходимо вставить в цикл формирования товаров в контроллере каталога категории (немного изменив):

```
#catalog/controller/product/category.php:

#straight before this peace of code:
$data['products'][] = array(
    'sort_order'  => $result['sort_order'],
    'product_id'  => $result['product_id'],
    #... code ...
    #... code ...
)
#put this spell:
$related_to = array();
$related_to_results = $this->model_catalog_product->getProductRelated($this->request->get['product_id']);
foreach ($results as $result) {
    #... code ...
    #... code ...
    $related_to = array(
        'product_id'  => $result['product_id'],
        #repeat all the code
        );
}
#and finally add this to $data['products'][]:
 $data['products'][] = array(
    'sort_order'  => $result['sort_order'],
    'product_id'  => $result['product_id'],
    #... code ...
    #... code ...
    'related'     => $related_to//<-------
)
```

В результате, в `catalog/view/theme/dafault(your_theme)/category.tpl`, в цикле  `<?php foreach ($products as $product) { ?>` будет доступен массив товаров, рекомендуемых в этому $product['related']. Разворачивать через foreach, солить по вкусу, довести до готовности.

Comment: Не совсем то что мне нужно. я ошибся. это называется похожие продукты в самой карточке товара. и в самой карточке эти товары выводятся, но мне нужно для каждого товара на странице категории вывести эти товары

Comment: @Алексей Пуха я же вам прописал рецепт. Для страницы "катерория" всё точно так же.

Comment: я наверное плохо описал задачу. мне НЕ нужно вывести где то на странице категории рекомендуемые товары, которые я добавил вручную в этот модуль.  когда я наполняю сайт товарами я заполняю значение многих атрибутов товара и в вкладке связи в самом низу есть пункт похожие товары. у меня есть возможность очень легко добавить товары туда и когда я перехожу на карточку товара на сайте я вижу основной товар и похожие товары.

Comment: а теперь я хочу чтоб когда я захожу в категорию, я видел много товаров категории(это уже конечно ж реализовано по дефолту) но в каждом из этих товаров(не переходя в саму карточку товара) еще хочу видеть (перед кнопкой купить например) те самые похожие товары(но только ссылки), которые я могу увидеть перейдя в саму карточку товара

Comment: Пытался переписать код файлов категории по аналогии с файлами продукта. Пока не получилося

Comment: @Алексей Пуха обновил ответ