# Модуль Рекомендуемые товары Опенкарт 2?

Tags: opencart

Привет всем!
Подскажите такой же модуль [prntscr.com/ghv5u8](http://prntscr.com/ghv5u8) где можно выбрать товары, и выводит на странице продукта и категории. То есть для каждого товара должна быть свои Рекомендуемые товары, сейчас есть дефолтно такой функционал, но надо второй.
Спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

В разделе **Дополнения -> Модули** добавляете новый экземпляр модуля **Рекомендуемые** Даёте ему имя, запоняете, сохраняете.

Далее переходите в раздел **Дизайн -> Схемы (Layouts)**. Там выбираете из списка предустановленных схем ту, в которой хотите вывести новый модуль. Схемы имеют названия страниц и разделов сайта, поэтому разобраться будет не сложно. В вашем случае это схемы **Категория** и **Продукт**.

Немного о том, как работать со схемами, можете почитать [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/697041/%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4-%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B4%D1%83%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%8B%D1%85-%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D0%B2-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BA%D0%B5-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B5-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B8/697202#697202)

**UPD:**

По аналогии с ответом по ссылке выше, вы проделываете все те же действия. Разница лишь в том, что код дублируется не в другой, а в тот же файл контроллера **product.php**. Вам лишь надо задать новому массиву имя, отличное от **$data['products']**, как в контроллере, так и в файле представления **product.tpl ($products)**

Comment: Вы хоть читали описание вопроса ?

Comment: @Seva - "выводит на странице продукта и категории" это из вашего вопроса?

Comment: Да но суть вопроса не в том. Короче надо сделать такой же поле под каждом товаре в админке https://prnt.sc/ghv5u8

Comment: перейдите по ссылке из ответа, так описан этот случай для карты товара.

Comment: Господи  боже мой